# Unzip a file an upload all its content to S3 using Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I am building an API in Rails, and one of the calls will get a zip file containing a static HTML site, upload it to S3, and return the public URL.

What's the best way to approach this? I'm thinking of unzipping the file in Heroku's tmp directory and using [s3_uploader](https://github.com/chrishein/s3_uploader) to upload all its content on S3.

Is it worth using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody answered, so I'll quickly explain how I approached this issue.

I'm using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to upload the zip file to S3, and I'm calling the unzip method asynchronously with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem. This is pretty well explained on [Heroku's dev center page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

The unzip method downloads and extracts the S3 zip file on Heroku's tmp folder, then uploads it back to S3 using the [s3_uploader](https://github.com/chrishein/s3_uploader) gem. This works quite nicely, the only thing that I have to sort out at some point is deleting the unzipped folder when a model entity gets deleted.